# Quantify performance based on memory usage

Tags: r

How can the performance of different functions (or approaches) be quantified? I'm thinking something like `system.time()` or `microbenchmark::microbenchmark()` but for memory usage. In this example, say I want to compare `foo1()` vs `foo2()`. I tried tinkering with `gc()` but can't get it to work for comparing.

```
set.seed(42)
x = sample(1:100000)
y = sample(1:100000)

foo1 = function(){
    S = x + y
    return(tail(which(S == max(S)), 1))
}

foo2 = function(){
    S = x[1] + y[1]
    i = 1
    for (ind in 2:length(x)){
        if ((x[ind] + y[ind]) > S){
            S = x[ind] + y[ind]
            i = ind
        }
    }
    return(i)
}

identical(foo1(), foo2())
```

Comment: Maybe the new-ish bench package from rstudio, which tracks memory as well as time?

Comment: @Frank, that's new to me. So, we'd be looking at `mem_alloc` after running `mark()`?

Comment: I think so. I haven't used it yet myself. In case this gets closed as a tool request, you could also take it to chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public